# accessing vpn database through eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, vpn

im working with jsp, i access a database via vpn. I want to move to eclipse to do this, is there a plug in i can use or something for access to the vpn?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setup VPN access at operating system level according to your VPN-provider's instructions. Then use Eclipse DTP (DataTools) to access the database as if it was on the local network.